# How to remove line breaks/new lines in csv with python

Tags: python, pandas

```
simple code 

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('problematic.csv', sep='|',quotechar='"')
pandas_df = df.replace({r'\\r': ''}, regex=True)
pandas_df = pandas_df.replace({r'\\n': ''}, regex=True)
print(pandas_df.head())
```

i have input
INPUT -

```
ID  |  NAME   | VILLAGE  |   PENSION    -----HEADER

001 |  XYZ    |  RAMG    |    1500   -----ROW1


002 |  DINAL                        
      SHAMSUDH
      DHON 
|  SHIWA   |    2090
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
ID  |  NAME  |   VILLAGE  |   PENSION    

001 |  XYZ    |  RAMG     |   1500

002 |  DINAL SHAMSUDH  DHON  |  SHIWA   |    2090
```

Comment: You're just trying to replace newlines with nothing, right?  You're making it very complicated.  `pdf = df.replace('\n','')`

Comment: your problem is with the parameter "lineterminator", you should preprocessed the raw data to avoid fake new line signal ('\n')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the redundant newline characters prior to reading the csv in pandas. You could do so by with by opening the file, reading it with `readlines()`, which will create a list of lines. Then you can remove the newline characters from every item in the list that does not contain three `|` characters:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('problematic.csv') as f:
  text = f.readlines()
  text = ' '.join([i.replace('\n', '').strip() if i.count('|') <3 else i for i in text])

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='|',quotechar='"')
```

Output:

|  | ID | NAME | VILLAGE | PENSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | XYZ | RAMG | 1500 |
| 1 | 2 | DINAL SHAMSUDH DHON | SHIWA | 2090 |

Note that this example assumes that `-----HEADER` is not part of the csv file. If it is you can filter it out with `replace()`.